# What is slowing QGIS the most when opening form?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, performance, attribute-form

I made a complete form on QGIS, following the best way, according to me, to make it fast and easy to use.

But, as I progressed in developing my form, QGIS went slower and slower to open it (almost 4 sec). I improved it to lower this opening time to 3 seconds. But now, I wonder if I can do better.

The form is composed of 31 fields.
The length of each field is just a bit oversized.
There is 5 integer, 5 real and 21 string.

The layer has 2 relations with 2 others layers:

- one to add a list of pictures
- the other to make a list of species

11 fields are "value relation". The relation always is made with delimited text layer, composed on few lines (between 30 to 100; except one with 600 lines).
Each list can be in English or in French; one layer is used to select language and QGIS will show the list which matches with selected language.

Code:

```
"Language" = array_to_string(aggregate('LANGUAGE','array_agg',"Language"))
```

The name of each field depends on the selected language, also using a delimited text layer ("Alias) and an `"ID"`.

```
array_get(
    aggregate(
        'Alias',
        'array_agg',
        "Alias"
        ),
    array_find(
        aggregate(
            'Alias',
            'array_agg',
            "id"|| '-' || "Language"
            ),
            '12-' ||
            array_to_string(
                aggregate(
                    'LANGUAGE',
                    'array_agg',
                    "Language"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
```

We can record different kind of information, by choosing a "category". Each container of the form is shown depending on the chosen category (15 categories).
Ex: category 1 chosen; so the compartment 1 is shown (not the others).
Using this code: `"COMP_Val" = 1`

I'm also using default values to calculate coordinates, altitude or orientation, and constraints to make sure each field is filled when the right category has be chosen (especially to avoid error when using on QFIELD).

Is there a method to respect to avoid latencies when opening the form?

I never noticed a sudden operation that slowed down it, the opening time of the form has increased slowly.

[image]

---

I have this log message :
Unbalanced call to leaveUpdateMode() w.r.t. enterUpdateMode()
In the OGR category.
But I have no idea about the origin of this issue.

---

I checked the settings according to your explanations, but I have no hidden browser paths.

I already reduced the opening time by deleting 7 fields with value relations, then I added another relation between my layer and a new layer, which contains the 7 fields.

I also modified all the lists. Now I have 1 group of French lists and 1 group of English lists. I use the lists that I need in my project (French or English).
It allowed me to simplify many of my expressions. For example, I'm not asking QGIS anymore to search for the selected language.

From 3 seconds, I decreased the opening time to a bit less than 2 seconds.

I think, each operation takes a little time to execute, but none of them is really slowing the project. This means I can't reduce this time except by deleting other fields or operations.

Comment: Check if you have several drives enabled in QGIS 3.22.x I had a similar problem witch I workaround by keeping only one dive opened. Look into settings - options - Hidden browser paths.

Comment: aggregates upon aggregates are going to be slow. What is the format of your data source? If you can, use a fast format, not something text based for example.

Comment: All the lists used are .csv documents. I imported them by adding a delimited text layer. I'm using aggregate when I want to give en alias of my fields.    >array_get(aggregate('Alias','array_agg',"Alias"),array_find(aggregate('Alias','array_agg',"id"),'16'))   Here I'm searching the 16th id and its alias (because alias cas change)

Comment: Thank you for pointing the issue with "aggregates upon aggregates". I changed it for something simpler : attribute(get_feature_by_id('Alias',16+1),'Alias') (I change the id to get the Alias I want). Result: Approximatively 1sec 30 to open.    Should I change something with .csv documents ? I can open them as Shapefiles without geometry.

Comment: Hi, I deleted all the "delimited text" layers and convert them to shapefiles. Now the form is opening in less than 1sec (around 80ms). Your other advise was also really helpful ! Thank you !